# How can i implement a tipping feature(+ take a percentage % from each transaction)?

Tags: paypal, architecture, stripe-payments, integration, payment

I'm working on this feature to allow users to tip other users (willing to use paypal or stripe),
The feature itself is easy to implement but i want to take a percentage from each percentage or even a fixed amount?

### Thank you

---